# Uploading a file to Google Drive

Tags: android, google-drive-android-api

I am developing an app which uses Google Drive to share files. The activity for Google Drive is launched by the code below.

```
int REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER = 1;
credential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(mActivity,DriveScopes.DRIVE);
startActivityForResult(credential.newChooseAccountIntent(),REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER);
```

The app has the following permissions in the manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
```

and it is configured on Google console.

However, I am always getting request code 131073 onActivityResult.

Can you please tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Check this link : http://koklimabc.blogspot.in/2012/12/how-to-programatically-upload-file-from.html

Comment: I got my solution Just I was starting the Google drive activity inside the fragment without take reference of parent activity. Now as I uploading the file on Google Drive by the below metheod   file = service.files().insert(body, mediaContent).execute(); getting android.gms.auth.googleauthioexception